# R3 register of ARM-Cortex M4F suddenly changes value right after ldr instruction

Tags: assembly, gcc, arm, cortex-m, microchip

I have this really strange bug where an ldr instruction first loads in a valid value into the R3 register, then when I use the debugger to step over one instruction, it all of a sudden contains the value 0x0.
This assembly is generated from C++ by GCC9 for C++17.

The instructions are:

```
ldr r3, [r7, #12]    ; after this instruction r3 will have value 0x20009da0
ldr r3, [r3, #8]     ; after this instruction r3 will have value 0x20003e28
ldr r3, [r3]         ; after this instruction r3 will have value 0x00020a2c, the value at this addr is 0000a1a9
ldr r3, [r3]         ; after this instruction r3 will suddenly have value 0x00000000
ldr r2, [r7, #12]        
ldr r2, [r2, #8]         
mov r0, r2       
blx r3               ; at this point r3 still has value 0x00000000 causing the reset handler to be called
```

Shouldn't r3 have the value `0x0000a1a9` after the last `ldr` instruction?

To give some more information, I am developing for Microchip's ATSAMD51J20A using Microchip Studio with GCC9 installed.
The code in question where this occurs is:

```cpp
auto& socket = m_device.get_socket();
```

where `get_socket()` has as its return value a reference to an interface class and the actual implementation of `get_socket()` returns a reference to a class which extends this interface.

Comment: Are you sure that @0x00020a2c contains 0000a1a9 ? Did you see that with the debugger ?

Comment: Yes that is the value I see at that address in the Memory Overview of the debugger.

Comment: This particular access is in flash, maybe check your flash wait states. Did you change the NVM wait states manually ?

Comment: I check the NVMCTRL->CTRLA.bit.AUTOWS value and it is set to 1, so the wait states should be set automatically.

Comment: Does the fault also happen without stepping ? And without a debugger at all ? Also, try to add a manual load before to see what you get (u32 v = \*(volatile u32*)0x00020a2c).

Comment: I tried adding `volatile uint32_t t = *((uint32_t *)0x00020a2c);` in front of the `m_device.get_socket()` call and t seems to also hold the value 0x000000. Also without stepping the same thing happens. Eventually I will press the pause button and it will be in the Reset_Handler, which is to be expected from address 0x000000.

Comment: Try to pinpoint with more tests. Try several identical manual loads (and put the volatile in the cast when loading, not the variable). Try loading adjacent addresses, try loading @0 and @4 (which should have non-zero values). Maybe disable the NVM cache, although I'm not sure it'd help.

Comment: sounds like a debugger issue not processor, try to eliminate the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I remember Microchip compilers having strange (timing?) issues where lines of repeated instructions behave in unexpected ways. I still don't know about the details but sometimes padding NOPs between these lines resolves the problem.